# P=QRS decomposition of given list -2 -unordered list

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation, code-request, partitions

This is an extended version of my previous post, [$P=QRS$ decomposition of given list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252637/p-qrs-decomposition-of-given-list)

Based on the answer and comment of @Bill,

> Form all permutations of P. Form Q as the first element of each of those, R as the second element and S all the rest of each perm. Then do this with R of length 2. And then of length 3. And ... until you are down to S of length 1. Now start over with Q of length 2, etc, etc, etc.

for length $3$, I have done this via

```
A3 = Permutations[{a1, a2, a3}]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A3], i++,
P[i] = Partition[A3[[i]], 1]];
 
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A3], i++,
 Q[i] = P[i][[1]];
 R[i] = P[i][[2]];
 S[i] = P[i][[3]]; ];
Table[Flatten[{Q[i], R[i], S[i]}], {i, 1, Length[A3]}]
```

It looks okay, but I am having trouble with length 4. With the same instruction I did

```
A4 = Permutations[{a1, a2, a3, a4}]
Length[A4]
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A4], i++,
 P[i] = Partition[A4[[i]], 1]
 ];

(*2+1+1*)
For[i = 1, i <= Length[A4], i++,
 Q1[i] = Flatten[{P[i][[1]], P[i][[2]]}];
 R1[i] = P[i][[3]];
 S1[i] = P[i][[4]];
  ]
(*1+2+1*)
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[A4], i++,
 Q2[i] = P[i][[1]];
 R2[i] = Flatten[{P[i][[2]], P[i][[3]]}];
 S2[i] = P[i][[4]];
  ]
(*1+1+2*)
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[A4], i++,
 Q3[i] = P[i][[1]];
 R3[i] = P[i][[2]];
 S3[i] = Flatten[{P[i][[3]], P[i][[4]]}];
 ]
```

But here the size does not agree with what I expected;  For length $4$ case there is three choices to divide, $(1,1,2), (1,2,1),(2,1,1)$ and by symmetry, for each of them there are $ 12$ of them so the total is $36$. But here individuals have $24$ and thus $24\times 3=72$.

> For example, $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with $(1,1,2)$ decomposition, we have $(1,2,34),(1,3,24),(1,4,23), (2,1,34),(2,3,14),(2,4,13),(3,1,24),(3,2,14),(3,4,12),(4,1,23),(4,2,13),(4,3,12)$ 12 cases [One can think of this first by chossing $2$ elements among $4$ and multiplying the degeneracy $2$]

For $P=QR$ decomposition of an unordered set, the subset is enough for whole possible cases, but in this case, after dividing into $P=QR$ and $R=R'S$, the total size should be increased, and there are some problems for injecting more possible lists into the first partitions.

Before this setup, I just plugging all the possible cases of length $4$ individually, but I realized this is very inefficient and even produces typos(human error) for length $5$ and more than length $5$ cases.

Besides permutations, I tried to formulate similar things with partitions command but I realized the assign function of partition only produces partitions up to its length, not partition into three pieces or more than three.  i.e., as a manual says

```
 Partition[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, 3, 1]
```

produces sequences of length 3 with offset 1...

Any ideas or explicit examples are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
A4={a1,a2,a3,a4};
(*ordered*)
p={A4};
i=Permutations[IntegerPartitions[Length[A4],{3}][[1]]];
t=Flatten[Outer[TakeList,p,i,1],1];
Q=Map[#[[1]]&,t];
R=Map[#[[2]]&,t];
S=Map[#[[3]]&,t];

A4={a1,a2,a3,a4};
(*unordered*)
p=Permutations[A4];
i=Permutations[IntegerPartitions[Length[A4],{3}][[1]]];
t=Flatten[Outer[TakeList,p,i,1],1];
Q=Map[#[[1]]&,t];
R=Map[#[[2]]&,t];
S=Map[#[[3]]&,t];
```

Test this without mercy. Look at the values of `p` and `i` and `t` to make absolutely certain that these are being precisely correctly partitioned into `Q` and `R` and `S`. Perhaps carefully line up corresponding items in `Q` and `R` and `S` and verify that each column of those three rows do partition all of `A4` and that every permutation of `A4` is correctly included and nothing else is. You really have to convince yourself that this is exactly correct, not just see that a few items seem to be OK and assume that everything must be OK. Then see if you can understand how to generalize this further.

I think I'm beginning to like this. That is dangerous. I need to think more.

Comment: Hello, using your code, with sorting and dividing multiplicities by hand, I obtain what I want, but wondering about the making size, and the divisions without explicitly.  I post this issue at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252816/p-qrs-decomposition-of-given-list-3-unordered-list

Comment: I mean, I count the total number by counting multiplicities explicitly. What I want to know in my new posted question is without doing "explicit counting" how one can make consistent counting from the ground. 

About divisions: For the length 5, case there are 2 possible integerpartitions, so I made [Length[A5],{3}][[1]] and [Length[A5],{3}][[2]] explicitly and do the same thing as length 4; In the new post, I want to know whether there is a systematic way to do this for an arbitrary length of a list; In some sense, we love "generalization" so I make a new post regarding this two issues!